# Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, facebook

I've built a flutter app on windows PC and now I ran it on a VM Mac, I didn't all the right configurations and the app does build successfully.

I'm using the Facebook login SDK and I followed the instructions.

when I run the app on the simulator I get the error message: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit

Any tips for solving this?

I tried:

- pod deintegrate > pod install
- deleting DerivedData folder and rerunning

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?  Where does this error come from?  How do I correctly install Facebook SDK?  How do I reinstall Facebook SDK?  Can I run Xcode with VM?  Or else?

Comment: @ElTomato my question is where does this error come from and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Open yout Target project on XCode and add FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework  to Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content:

[image]

Be careful because you have 2 available, you need to select the one inside Pods:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Question :- Flutter (iOS) - Library not loaded: '@rpath/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit'**

Solution :- *Xcode Version 14.3 (14E222b)*

Follow below simple steps;

Open Xocde -> Select Runner Target -> General Tab -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content ->

Add -> **FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework**

[image]